# Is there a way to create a DOM object, given its rendered string?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to create a DOM object from the whole string, not just the innerHTML? I have a string in the form of a complete rendered DOM:

```
<some_tag_name class=... id=...>inner text</some_tag_name>     (1)
```

and want to directly create a DOM object out of it. I know that there is a way to do:

```
e = document.createElement("some_tag_name")
e.innerHTML = ...
e.className = ...
e.id = ...
```

but when I do that, I have to extract the innerhtml part from the string (1) that I have, and analyze the tag type and all the attributes and assign that to `e` separately. I want to do all that simply from the string in the form of (1) that I have.

**Edit**

I followed the answers, but it was trickier than it seemed at first. The problem is that when you have a string representing things like `tr`, `td`, etc., and you try to put that as the innerHTML to a temporarily created `div`, the browser automatically adds extra tags outside of it. The following is my workaround to overcome this problem, where `c` is the string and `e` is the created element:

```
var cTagName = c.match(new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]+'))[0].toUpperCase();
var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.innerHTML = c;
    e = e.children[0];
//// When the type of `e' does not match what `c' expects, the browser
////    automatically modifies the type of c. The following is to undo this.
if(e.tagName.toUpperCase() != cTagName){
    e = document.createElement("table");
    e.innerHTML = c;
    e = e.children[0];
};
if(e.tagName.toUpperCase() != cTagName){
    e = document.createElement("tbody");
    e.innerHTML = c;
    e = e.children[0];
};
if(e.tagName.toUpperCase() != cTagName){
    e = document.createElement("tr");
    e.innerHTML = c;
    e = e.children[0];
};
```

Comment: Not sure what yo're trying to do with it, but you can create a div element, set the innerHTML to your string, and get the children out of the element you created. Or, there's always jQuery, which actually does that exact same thing just in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always do:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<some> ... </some>"
var e = div.children[0];
```

(or if you're using jQuery, simply `$("<some ... >")[0]`).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems robust. I was wondering between josh3736's answer, and yours. Both look good.

Comment: After doing this, is there a way to remove the original "div" element `e` without destroying `div.children[0]`? I am going to use this a lot, and, and at later random point, the `div.children[0]` objects will be deleted entirely. the  am afraid lots of these empty "div"s will be existing. Will they be garbage collected?

Comment: Yep, they'll be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried your way, and actually, there was one problem. I overcame that problem as I show in the edit to the question. Do you have any thoughts about it; good or bad?

Comment: Yep, I guess you do need to do that sort of thing. jQuery handles all of this for you, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) property.

```
var el = document.createElement('tag');
document.body.appendChild(el); // The element must be appended to the DOM before
                               // setting outerHTML.  Otherwise, it will throw a
                               // NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR.
el.outerHTML='<some_tag_name class=... id=...>inner text</some_tag_name>';
```

---

Given that Firefox is a little behind the times on this one, it's probably safer to just create a wrapper `div` and set its `innerHTML`.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = '<some_tag_name class=... id=...>inner text</some_tag_name>';
```

Comment: Note that Firefox did not support this until version 11.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that support for `outerHTML` was only recently added in Firefox (v11, March 2012), though most other browsers have supported it for a long time.  So this isn't really a cross browser solution right now. (edit: Ninjad by @Rob because I had to answer the door :-P)

Comment: Thanks, your will be the best solution after a short while. For now, I will go with Ben's solution.

Comment: @Rob, Andy: thanks, didn't realize that.  It is a little ridiculous that it took [11 years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92264) to fix that...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
var myDiv = $('<div class="my-div">This is my div!</div>');
```

Comment: Sadly, I do not use jQuery... If I did, it would be a good solution.

Comment: Note that [behind the scenes](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/manipulation.js#L664), jQuery is simply creating a wrapper `div` and setting its `innerHTML`.